# Can one pray home when it is raining heavy?

Tags: salat, fiqh

The following hadiths says that prophet himself allowed men to pray at home when the weather conditions was adverse. But in my knowledge Muslim do not follow it today. I have never heard a single call from the mosque when they would say, we can pray home and we had terrible weather back home. That means continues rain for days + lots of mudd and even floods. But they would never announce one can pray home. What is the ruling? Why don't we follow the prophet?

What should be the ruling in areas where there is *excessive* cold and snow. It causes the same bad condition. Makes it difficult to get to the mosque + more risky because of slip/accident. Should praying at home be allowed then? Again why don't we follow it as Sunni Muslim? Is there any sect that is following it?

**[Sahih Bukhari Volume 1, Book 11, Number 635](http://sunnah.com/search/very-cold-and-stormy-night)**:

> Narrated Nafi':
>
> Once on a very cold and stormy night, Ibn 'Umar pronounced the Adhan
>   for the prayer and then said, "Pray in your homes." He (Ibn 'Umar)
>   added. "On very cold and rainy nights Allah's Apostle used to order
>   the Mu'adhdhin to say, 'Pray in your homes.' "

**[Sahih Bukhari Volume 1, Book 11, Number 637](http://sunnah.com/search/muddy-day-and-when-the)**:

> Narrated 'Abdullah bin Al-Harith:
>
> Ibn Abbas addressed us on a (rainy and) muddy day and when the
>   Mu'adh-dhin said, "Come for the prayer" Ibn 'Abbas ordered him to say,
>   "Pray in your homes." The people began to look at one another with
>   surprise as if they did not like it. Ibn 'Abbas said, "It seems that
>   you thought ill of it but no doubt it was done by one who was better
>   than I (i.e. the Prophet). It (the prayer) is a strict order and I
>   disliked to bring you out."
>
> Ibn 'Abbas narrated the same as above but he said, "I did not like you
>   to make you sinful (in refraining from coming to the mosque) and to
>   come (to the mosque) covered with mud up to the knees."

Comment: "But they would never announce one can pray home" - then edit also "Can one pray home when it is raining heavy?" and "Should praying at home be allowed then?"

Answer (score 3):

You can always pray Allah at home (*at least if you are not a neighborhood of a mosque*), however going to the mosques is as encouraged as the Holy Prophet --peace be upon him-- ordered a blind man to tie a rope from the mosque to his home to be able to take part in Jamaa'at in the mosque, see e.g. [1-3]. That is, difficulty of going to mosque is not an acceptable excuse. However, the Hadith you are citing in your question may addresses the probable occurance of floods which is very common in Mecca. If so then going to mosques would be dangerous for their lives, a more sever condition than being difficult to go to the mosques, and this would be acceptable.

- [1] تهذيب الأحكام (تحقيق خرسان)، ج‏3، ص: 266
- [2] روضة المتقين في شرح من لا يحضره الفقيه (ط - القديمة)، ج‏2، ص: 484
- [3] وسائل الشيعة، ج‏8، ص: 293

Comment: There is only mention of cold and rain but not floods! Your answer would be a little more useful if the references were actually links. Thanks

Comment: @thetruthseeker, as a Shia I cannot address the authenticity of the Ahadeeth you have quoted in your question, instead just tried to justify it with such a description. the flood and such things were the only probabilities that I could think about, maybe others can better justify it or else announce the Ahadeeth to be Dha3eef or etc. The references are books that I have, I'm not sure if you would be able to find all of them on the web. But feel free to ask about any Hadeeth that you want.

Comment: You automatically come to flood when it says extreme cold and rain. They are two different thing. It is very rare to have extreme cold during floods. Also flood do not come during heavy rain. You can argue though that hadith is wrong but I believe it is correct hadith.

Comment: @thetruthseeker, actually I came to the notion of flood from a heavy rain for cities like Mecca wherein a heavy rain can easily result in a flood.

Answer (score 1):

Actually now-a-days the situation is little bit different.  The technologies and inventions are increasing for more easy to work and go anywhere for us.
If a situation comes that heavy rain is going outside and then people can travel to masjid by a cars, vans and buses. The  Mu'adh-dhin do not say "Pray in your homes", because of having these facilities. But this excuse is only for those people whose can't able to travel in cars, vans and buses or they have not these facilities.

Comment: It doesn't matter how technologically advance the muslims become. If there's a 'rukhsat' in deen then that should be availed just like the 'Safar'/travelling situation. Back then 75km was a lot but now its not much as we have cars etc, so does that mean we are not musafir if we travel ~75km? Yes we are. The rules apply regardless of any advance technology we may have in our use.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the same Hadith is for a heavy stormy rain or flood and if aperson come out from his home, in such circumstances than Allah is not responsible for his safety.
If there is no danger to one life and aperson may reach to masjid without getting effect to be his Pak or clean towards his clothes and body,than what ,s problem to go and pray in masjid.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking your time to take our [tour], check our [help] to learn more about how this site works and what is on- or off-topic here. Also I'd recommend you to elaborate your answer to make it  more useful see [answer].